# When to initialise classes that use Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

HI so im running into some trouble with configuring the FirebaseApp in Swift using FirebaseApp.configure(). Ive tried configuring within the AppDelegate using @UiApplicationDelegateAdaptor, in the App's init() and also in an ObservableObject that I am using firebase's authentication product within. Out of all of those options why does the ObservableObject's class init first? How can I make sure that .configure() is occuring before I initialise classes using Firebase? As im expanding into the other products im unsure of how to use each of them AFTER i have configured the FirebaseApp without checking for it in each instance.

Thanks

I have tried following the Firebase documentation and error messaging of placing .configure() within the AppDelagate and using the @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor property wrapper. I have also tried the App struct's init().